# LU factorization accuracy

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

I'm doing some experiments with LU factorization (without pivoting). Basically I have a 2x2 matrix and a $b$ vector and I try to solve Ax=b. $A$ looks like: \begin{pmatrix}a&1\\1&1\\ \end{pmatrix} and $b$ looks like \begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\ \end{pmatrix}

I let $a$ go towards $0$ to experiment what effects it has on the relative error in $x$. As expected, the relative error increases as $a$ decreases. I know that the problem is that as $a$ gets small, roundoff errors in $a$ get severely amplified by the factorization process. But I'm wondering if there is a way to say something about how big the relative error will be as $a$ goes to zero (some kind of upper bound). I am computing the condition numbers for the $L$ and the $U$ matrix. But these only appear to say something about the error in x with respect to small changes in b.

Answer (score 0):

We assume that your computer works with $N$ digits. The following calculation is valid for any $b$.

The error about $x$ is very small when $a$ tends to $0$. If you want a great error, then we must assume that $a$ tends to $1$. Your matrix is symmetric; then, for $||.||_2$, $cond(A)=\sup(|spectrum(A)|)/\inf(|spectrum(A)|)$. Since the eigenvalues are (when $a$ is close to $1$) $\approx 2$ and $\approx (a-1)/2$, $cond(A)\approx 4/|a-1|$. If $cond(A)\approx 10^k$, then $x$ is known with $N-k$ significant digits, that is equivalent to say that the relative error on $x$ is $10^{k-N}$.

Remark. The error on $x$ is great when $a$ tends to $\pm \infty$.